# Separated Apps - but shared react-js-core

Tags: reactjs

I plan to rewrite parts of our Site using React.js (Apps have only our Stylesheets, base HTML structure in common, they use different Data-Sources).

But what I need to know, before I start:
Is it possible to reuse the React Core

`import React, { Component } from 'react';`

or must each "App" load/compile it's own, -> overhead per App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an importing into the scope of your module, really webpack will import React only once.

If you want to make a few bundles of your app, it will be correct to exclude React (and other libraries) from bundles to prevent loading it many times. For this case webpack provides an option `externals`.

[Webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)

[Issue about React as externals](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275)